# Readonly и disabled

Tags: html

Всем привет.

В общем, у меня такая проблема: я добавил элементу `<input>` значение readonly и disabled. В GoogleChrome все цифры и буквы пишутся серым цветом, и их нельзя изменить. В FireFox же все так же, но сам `<input>` получает серый фон. Как этот фон убрать?

Comment: Задать ему через CSS другой фон?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Lk9ey8z9/